# can't click in a TextBox with an Expander

Tags: c#, xaml, expander

After adding an `Expander` over a `TextBox`, I'm not able to click on the original `TextBox`. 
For example

```
<Grid Background="Yellow" Focusable="False">
    <TextBox Margin="0,20,0,0"  Background="Azure" Width="150" Height="30"/>
    <Expander  Focusable="False">
        <Grid Background="White" >
            <TextBox  Background="LightGreen" Width="150" Height="30"/>
        </Grid>
    </Expander>
</Grid>
```

the above azure TextBox is not clickable: I have to tab in it...

[image]

... while the green one works fine

[image]

Edit
I've tried to add false focusable in the expander

Comment: Focusable = false?

Comment: @Chris Wohlert Thank you! I've tried, without success

Comment: You can try adding focusable=false to the expander. Perhaps that's what Chris said.

Comment: @PhiterFernandes nothing changes with focusable = false in the Expander...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Expander is placed on top of your azure TextBox (they both are placed on the same grid in the same cell 0,0), so azure TextBox can not be clicked. If you change their z-order by placing azure TextBox after Expander, then azure TextBox will become clickable (but it will prevent green TextBox to be clickable):

```
<Grid Background="Yellow" Focusable="False">    
  <Expander  Focusable="False">
    <Grid Background="White" >
        <TextBox  Background="LightGreen" Width="150" Height="30"/>
    </Grid>
  </Expander>
  <TextBox Margin="0,20,0,0"  Background="Azure" Width="150" Height="30"/>
</Grid>
```

You cannot have 2 TextBoxes to be clickable, if they are placed on top of one another.

To achieve your goal (to access one TextBox when the Expander is expanded and the other one when the Expander is collapsed) you can collapse azure TextBox, when expander is expanded. Here is an example how to do it with Triggers (or you can do it in code for simplicity):

```
<Grid Background="Yellow">
<Expander Name="Expander">      
  <Grid Background="White" >
    <TextBox  Background="LightGreen" Width="150" Height="30"/>
  </Grid>
</Expander>
<TextBox Name="AzureBox" Margin="0,20,0,0"  Background="Azure" Width="150" Height="30">
  <TextBox.Style>
    <Style>
      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=Expander, Path=IsExpanded}" Value="True">
          <Setter Property="TextBox.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"></Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: I tried this, but in this way the TextBox in the Expander is not reachable. My objective is to access one TextBox when the Expander is expanded and the other one when the Expander is collapsed.

Comment: Then you can change visibility of azure textbox to collapsed, when expander is expanded. I added example to my answer

Comment: "Your Expander is placed on top of your azure TextBox", but it is collapsed, not visible. The original behaviour still looks like a bug afaik: what am I missing?

Comment: "but it is collapsed, not visible". No, It is visible, just not expanded (Visibility.Collapsed and IsExpanded=False are different). Even if expander is not expanded it is still visible and takes mouse events as a topmost element in grid.

Comment: It is visible, but it is getting mouse events from a non visible part (when it's not expanded). Look at my solution.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an issue with the dimensions of the Expander when it is collapsed: the expansion must be caused by its internal content.
The following xaml works as expected.

```
<Grid Background="Yellow" Height="290" Width="290">
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0"  Background="Azure" Width="150" Height="30"/>
    <Expander ExpandDirection="Down"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Margin="5,0,0,0" >
        <Grid Background="White" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="290" Width="290">
            <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,5,45" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="LightGreen" Width="150" Height="30"/>
        </Grid>
    </Expander>
</Grid>
```